# How to add a folder with .desktop files?

Tags: command-line, gnome, launcher, appmenu

I know that if you want to add a .desktop entry it must be added in `/usr/share/applications`, however, what I want is to add an extra folder where it can host .desktop files.

If I run update-desktop-database you can see that programs like snapd or flatpak create their own directories where they host their .desktop

```
The databases in [/usr/share/ubuntu/applications, /home/cactus/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications, /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications, /usr/local/share/applications, /usr/share/applications, /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications] could not be updated.
```

My idea is to add a folder `/opt/applications` where I can save .desktop of my self-compiled applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to      [GNOME Desktop System Administration Guide Customizing Menus : Desktop Entry Files](https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/2.32/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en)

> Desktop entry files must reside in the `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications`
> directory and must have a .desktop file extension. If `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` <sup>1</sup>
> is not set, then the default path is `/usr/share` is used. This also
> implies that user specific desktop entries may be located at
> `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications` which is searched first. If `$XDG_DATA_HOME`
> is not set, then the default path `~/.local/share` is used. Desktop
> entries are collected from all directories in the `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`
> environment variable. Directories which appear first in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`
> are given precedence when there are several .desktop files with the
> same name.
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup> `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is the environment variable defined in the [XDG base directory specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/Standards/basedir-spec).</sup>

So if `$XDG_DATA_HOME` does not say otherwise, you can place per-user .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`. If you want a system-wide custom location, you should be able to add it to `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` ex.

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/opt:$XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

See also [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Comment: That works perfect. What I did was add the following in /etc/profile: "XDG_DATA_DIRS=/opt:$XDG_DATA_DIRS".
Now all applications in /opt/applications are loaded by gnome, and I can see them in the launcher.
Many thanks!

Comment: A more elegant approach rather than directly editing a system file that may be overwritten by an update would be to add a one-liner script in /etc/profile.d. All these scripts are sourced by /etc/profile

Answer (score 5):

You can use `~/.local/share/applications` under your user's home folder to keep `.desktop` files that you want to have available for that user only.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, but that's not what I want to do. My idea is to have the applications isolated, to be able to copy them easily from one computer to another. However, the answer below is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @SebastiánCastro you can put a directory *inside* `~/.local/share/applications` (e.g., `~/.local/share/applications/my-special-applications`). Personally, I'd do that instead of modifying environment variables - you just need to copy the directory in the new system's `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 2):

Not a fundamental answer to your actual question (i.e., how to add your custom directory to host .desktop launchers), but I suggest you could use `/usr/local/share/applications` for launchers of your self compiled applications that should be available system wide.

This directory is configured by default in Ubuntu in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, and its purpose is exactly for what you are looking for, i.e., make your manually installed `.desktop` files available in the menu systems of any user.